# How to load gltf files with gltf-rs crate?

Tags: opengl, rust, gltf

I'm attempting to load glTF files in Rust using gltf-rs, but I'm struggling to understand the structure and details of glTF, as I'm new to both OpenGL and 3D objects. Specifically, I want to load the contents of the glTF file as meshes and a model, and use them with OpenGL and glfw-rs. I've already created a Mesh and Model class (for .obj files) based on this tutorial: https://github.com/bwasty/learn-opengl-rs/blob/master/src/_3_model_loading/_1_model_loading.rs , but I'm unsure of the steps required to load glTF files in this way. Could you provide any helpful references or code examples that might assist me in this process?

i tried to look at the gltf reference image but i didnt understand the details since im new and im unsure about them

also i found an example code like this, is it valid? (im asking because it is from chatgpt and chatgpt gives inaccurate usage of libraries all the time)

```
use gltf::import;

fn main() {
    // Load the GLTF file
    let (gltf, buffers, _) = import("path/to/file.gltf").unwrap();

    // Render the meshes
    for mesh in gltf.meshes() {
        for primitive in mesh.primitives() {
            // Get the vertex and index buffers
            let reader = primitive.reader(|buffer| Some(&buffers[buffer.index()]));
            let positions = reader.read_positions().unwrap();
            let normals = reader.read_normals().unwrap();
            let indices = reader.read_indices().unwrap().into_u32();

            // TODO: Render the mesh using the vertex and index buffers
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fn CarregarGltf(tudo : &mut Vec<f32>, modelo : &str){
    let local_exe = std::env::current_dir().unwrap();
    let local = local_exe.display();
    let original_tamanho = tudo.len()/19;
    let (gltf, buffers, _) = gltf::import(format!("path/to/file.gltf",modelo)).unwrap();
    for m in gltf.meshes(){
        for p in m.primitives(){
            let r = p.reader(|buffer| Some(&buffers[buffer.index()]));
            let mut indices = Vec::new();
            if let Some(gltf::mesh::util::ReadIndices::U16(gltf::accessor::Iter::Standard(iter))) = r.read_indices(){
                for v in iter{
                    indices.push(v);
                }
            }
            let mut posicao = Vec::new();
            if let Some(iter) = r.read_positions(){
                for v in iter{
                    posicao.push(v);
                }
            }
            let mut textura = Vec::new();
            if let Some(gltf::mesh::util::ReadTexCoords::F32(gltf::accessor::Iter::Standard(iter))) = r.read_tex_coords(0){
                for v in iter{
                    textura.push(v);
                }
            }
            let mut normais = Vec::new();
            if let Some(iter) = r.read_normals(){
                for v in iter{
                    normais.push(v);
                }
            }
            let mut ossosid = Vec::new();
            if let Some(gltf::mesh::util::ReadJoints::U8(gltf::accessor::Iter::Standard(iter))) = r.read_joints(0){
                for v in iter{
                    ossosid.push(v);
                }
            }
            let mut pesos = Vec::new();
            if let Some(gltf::mesh::util::ReadWeights::F32(gltf::accessor::Iter::Standard(iter))) = r.read_weights(0){
                for v in iter{
                    pesos.push(v);
                }
            }
            for q in indices{
                // posição
                tudo.push(posicao[q as usize][0] as f32);
                tudo.push(posicao[q as usize][1] as f32);
                tudo.push(posicao[q as usize][2] as f32);
                // textura
                tudo.push(textura[q as usize][0] as f32);
                tudo.push(textura[q as usize][1] as f32);
                // normais
                tudo.push(normais[q as usize][0] as f32);
                tudo.push(normais[q as usize][1] as f32);
                tudo.push(normais[q as usize][2] as f32);
                // ossosid
                tudo.push(ossosid[q as usize][0] as f32);
                tudo.push(ossosid[q as usize][1] as f32);
                tudo.push(ossosid[q as usize][2] as f32);
                tudo.push(ossosid[q as usize][3] as f32);
                // pesos
                tudo.push(pesos[q as usize][0]);
                tudo.push(pesos[q as usize][1]);
                tudo.push(pesos[q as usize][2]);
                tudo.push(pesos[q as usize][3]);
                // aoffset
                tudo.push(0.0);
                tudo.push(0.0);
                tudo.push(0.0);
            }
        }
    }
    println!("VBO do \"{}\" : {}, {}", modelo, original_tamanho, tudo.len()/19-original_tamanho);
}
```

You need to organize the indexes to know the order in which the positions and normals will be organized within the OpenGL VBO, in the example I even added UV and Skeleton for Character Animation.